# Group MySQL data based on year

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have this query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY, '%Y') AS `year`
       , DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY, '%b') AS `month`
       , COUNT(odd_Id) as total, status, odd_date_created FROM odd_data
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY, '%m')
   HAVING DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY,'%Y') = 2018
```

$yearToDate will dynamically from select dropdown. When user select 2017, managed to get the data but if you select 2018 there is no data retrun.

Can somebody help me.

Comment: Are you sure there is data from 2018 with `status=1`? Posting some sample data would help.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Nick yes, there data up to March 20th. Even I paste the query in SQL Query using phpmyadmin it's return 0

Comment: What data type is odd_date_created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `GROUP BY` clause. Since you are grouping by month and the first data for each month is in 2017, the value of `DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY,'%Y')` in the select will almost certainly (although it's not guaranteed as there is no order implied) be 2017. You need to `GROUP BY` the year as well so that you get data for each month in each year. Then you can select specific years using `HAVING`. Note that you can use aliases in `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses, so you can rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY, '%Y') AS `year`,
       DATE_FORMAT(odd_date_created + INTERVAL -3 DAY, '%b') AS `month`,
       COUNT(odd_Id) as total, status, odd_date_created FROM odd_data
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY year, month
HAVING year = 2018
```

Note that having `status` and `odd_date_created` in this query is pointless as they will return random values from the set of entries which match the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses.